# How do I extract number of articles using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
statistic=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,value=".articlecount a")
print(statistic.text)
```

I'm trying to scrape a number of articles from Wikipedia but I'm getting this error.I'm not sure what to do because the selector name is correct and I added waiting time.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\38161\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\inspection.py", line 7, in <module>
    statistic=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,value=".articlecount a")
  File "C:\Users\38161\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 742, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
  File "C:\Users\38161\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 348, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\38161\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".articlecount a"}
  (Session info: chrome=120.0.6099.109); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF723BC4D02+56194]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF723B304B2]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7239D76AA]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF723A216D0]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF723A217EC]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF723A64D77]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF723A45EBF]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF723A62786]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF723A45C23]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF723A14A45]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF723A15AD4]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF723F3D5BB+3695675]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF723F96197+4059159]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF723F8DF63+4025827]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF723C5F029+687785]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF723B3B508]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF723B37564]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF723B376E9]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF723B28094]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFC06607344+20]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFC067426B1+33]
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
statistic=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,value=".articlecount a")
```

By:

```
statistic=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,value="#articlecount a")
```

Beacause you are using `.` but you are using css selector not class you have to use `#`

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
statistic=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,value="#articlecount a")
print(statistic.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch it using ID.

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver= webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page")
time.sleep(10)
count = driver.find_element(By.ID, "articlecount").text
print(count.split(" ")[0])
```